# assign a compatible function address to an operator overloaded function

Tags: c++, overloading

I suppose that the definition of a function is like assigning to the left part e.g. int f(int x) the right part that contains the code between braces id est: { ... code ... }.

So I would like to assign the address of an already defined function to an overloaded operator.
I do not define at once the overloaded operator because the defined function (in the real life case) is a templated function depending from a boolean parameter.

An example of code that I would like to be able to compile is bellow.
Is that possible somehow ? ( without defining the overloaded operator as a single statement call to the function )

```
    struct CNT{
        int c;
    };

    CNT addCNT(CNT a,CNT b){
        CNT r;
        r.c = (a.c<=b.c) ? a.c : b.c ;
        return r;
    }


//  CNT operator+(CNT a,CNT b){addCNT(a,b);}

    CNT operator+(CNT,CNT)=&addCNT;


    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        CNT a(10),b(20),c;
        c=a+b;
    }
```

Comment: You can only assign to variables, `operator+` is not a variable, it is a keyword.

Comment: @knivil the overloaded operator+ is just a function name. To that function name I want to assign the address of a compatible ( regarding parameters and results ) function.

Comment: There is a wonderful book called [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html) that every programmer should read. Chapter [2.5  Systems with Generic Operations](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-18.html#%_sec_2.5) is pertinent to this question.

Answer (score 1):

> the overloaded operator+ is just a function name.

But, what you were trying to do with:

```
CNT operator+(CNT,CNT)=&addCNT;
```

[which isn't valid] is the equivalent of assigning to a function *pointer*

I've fixed the compile errors and added such a pointer:

```
struct CNT {
    CNT(int x) { c = x; };
    CNT() { CNT(0); };

    int c;
};

CNT (*addCNTptr)(CNT a,CNT b);

CNT addCNT(CNT a,CNT b)
{
    CNT r;
    r.c = (a.c<=b.c) ? a.c : b.c ;
    return r;
}

CNT operator+(CNT a,CNT b){ return addCNTptr(a,b); }

//CNT operator+(CNT,CNT)=&addCNT;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    addCNTptr = addCNT;

    CNT a(10),b(20),c;
    c=a+b;

    return c.c;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible in C++.   The rules of the language simply don't permit it.

If you want a call to `operator+()` (or an expression like `a+b`) to resolve to a call to `addCNT()`, you need to define `operator+()` so its body does the call.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's not think about the operator, in C++ a function pointer is defined as the following:

```
CNT (*addThem)(CNT, CNT) = &addCNT;
```

Then, you can call it like this:

```
addThem(arg1, arg2);
```

However, what you tried to do (again forget operator) is a function declaration-ish statement:

```
CNT addThem+(CNT,CNT)=&addCNT;
```

That is not valid C++ and will not compile. The only place such a syntax is valid I know of is declaring a virtual function abstract:

```
virtual void f() = 0;
```

However, there is another step. You tried to do the same with `operator+`. Now you know you cannot assign a function pointer to a function declaration, you might want to do this:

```
CNT (*operator+)(CNT, CNT) = &addCNT;
```

But in this case again you will get a compilation error due to the use of `operator+` other than function declaration/definition.

Therefore, what you want is not possible directly. Of course you can create an inline function that redirects the call:

```
inline CNT operator+(CNT a, CNT b) { return addCNT(a, b); }
```

I will cite the standard when I find the relevant section.